# How do I graph a stepwise function?

Tags: python

```
%reset -f
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = arange(-3,5)
if any(x > 2):
    y = x**2
elif x <= 2:
    y = 2*x
print(x)
print(y)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

I am trying to graph a step function. 
For values of x>2, f(x)=x^2 
For values of x<=2, f(x)=2*x 
Test your function for -3<=x<=5.

For the question, I got this far and it seems like if statement is not working well. Please fix it for me.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since the function is continuous I do not see any problem

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = linspace(-3,5,1000)
y = zeros(x.shape)
y[x>2]= x[x>2]**2
y[x<2]= x[x<2]*2
print(x)
print(y)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Also in your code any(x>2) returns true in general, it wont analize each case individually. Another way could be:

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = arange(-3,5)
y = x.copy()
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] > 2:
        y[i] = x[i]**2
    elif x[i] <= 2:
        y[i] = 2*x[i]

print(x)
print(y)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```